# tabola library for extracting text from pdf in Python by area

Tags: python, pdf, extract, text-extraction

I am trying tabula and I am selecting text by area but some areas change between documents and I got some mismatched results. Check the images for a clearer explanation.

| Large size "Discriminação dos Serviços" | Small size "Discriminação dos Serviços" |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Check the size of "Discriminação dos Serviços"] | [image: Check the size of "Discriminação dos Serviços"] |

What are the alternatives for this kind of comportment in pdf files?

Answer (score 1):

If it's only two different sizes, maintain two sets of location data, and have a single piece of text you look for that tells you which size it is, like:

> Código do Serviço / Atividade

(I picked that text because, when looking at them side by side, it's the first text I could identify that had different locations.)

If the "lower" location matches, then it's the bigger of the two, and you will use the "large" location set.

Comment: there are multiple sizes. I think about running a for loop varying vertical position but that would result in slower processing. Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: Hmm. At least in the large vs small sample you shared, the only difference is that one section, _Código do Serviço / Atividade_. So, can you use fixed locations for the top portion, find  _Código..._, then make the locations in the bottom portion relative (offset) from _ _Código..._? Can you extend that idea to the other sizes?

Comment: Yes. The area where "Discriminação dos Serviços" begin is always the same. I will start from there and looping vertically until reach "Código do Serviço / Atividade". Then when it find that section, I save the position and find the other section from there.

Comment: This way will be slower. That's why I was thinking if would exist any other solution..

Comment: I just answered another question about finding text in a PDF, comparing PDFQuery (based on pdfminer) and PyMuPDF. It's not quite the same problem, but you might want to take a look at the PyMuPDF code, because that shows you how to very quickly iterate through all the text objects. <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72531460/extracting-text-in-known-bbox-from-pdf-pdfquery-too-slow/72540494#72540494>